# Gatling jms on SQS on diferent account

Tags: amazon-sqs, gatling

I've followed Gatling tutorial [here](https://gatling.io/2019/01/load-testing-aws-sqs-with-gatling/)

It works if the queue exists on the same account that I'm logged in, but if I try from another account with IAM role it doesn't work as it cannot resolve the queue URL correctly. How can I pass the accountId so the URL is correctly resolved?